# Tumblr RSS feed that only contains specific tags

Tags: rss, tumblr

I want to create a RSS feed based on the Tumblr tags I use. I want to submit ***some*** of my posts to a blog syndication service. To the blog syndicator I have to provide a RSS feed. But I don't want all posts to appear there. Is there a way I can do something like this?

- When I tag a post with a specific keyword: (eg: #blog) the post will
  get added to the RSS feed.
- If the #blog tag is not there, the post doesn't get included to the RSS feed.

Comment: Wow. I think I found the answer. I just found out that mydomain.tumblr.com/tagged/tagx gives the posts tagged with 'tagx'. So when I take mydomain.tumblr.com/tagged/tagx/rss I get the RSS feed. For safety's sake I'm taking it out through Feedburner. But this works. Great. Hope somebody will find it useful.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. I would suggest posting your finding as an answer, as your solved your own question :D. Its worth mentioning you can filter the main RSS feed using `<category>`

Comment: @mikedidthis Hi! I'm lacking enough reputation to answer my own question. Bad luck!

Comment: That sucks. Well when you have the power, come back and answer it, as its useful!

Comment: This question is better for [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but how to grab a Tumblr URL)

Answer (score 7):

OP found the answer themselves here it is:

```
mydomain.tumblr.com/tagged/tagx/rss
```

Adding `/rss` after a tumblr URL apparently generates an RSS feed (probably only if the blog has enabled RSS).

Comment: I think they may have just disabled this feature. My feeds stopped working today.